# Help with CTE syntax in SQL

Tags: sql-server, cte

I am new to SQL, I tried to create a CTE, but I get a red squiggle under the **AS** and I am getting an error message in the process of executing the syntax:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 117 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This is the SQL syntax, any help would be great:

```
WITH CTE_Grand_Harvest_Total AS (
SELECT 
    zardi, COUNT(zardi) AS Count_ZARDI, SUM(Weight) AS Sum_Weight, Total_Harvest, Total_Harvest*COUNT(zardi)*SUM(Weight) AS Grand_Total
FROM 
    S1_PH_CROPS_clean_final_minus_money_matters
WHERE  
    Work.dbo.S1_PH_CROPS_clean_final_minus_money_matters.cropNamePH = 'Maize'
GROUP BY 
    Total_Harvest, zardi
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CTE (common table expression) is actually only part of a `SELECT` statement. It's something you define before you actually `SELECT` data. You could look at it as a kind of pre-selection of data before you are actually retrieving data from that subset of data (from the CTE).

You can see this in the Microsoft Learn article explaining the `SELECT` statement:

```
<SELECT statement> ::=    
    [ WITH { [ XMLNAMESPACES ,] [ <common_table_expression> [,...n] ] } ]  -- <== The CTE bit
    <query_expression>   
    [ ORDER BY <order_by_expression> ] 
    [ <FOR Clause>]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]   
<query_expression> ::=   
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }   
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }  
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ]   
<query_specification> ::=   
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   -- <======== ACTUAL START OF A STANDARD SELECT
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
    < select_list >   
    [ INTO new_table ]   
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ <GROUP BY> ]
```

<sup>***Reference:**

[SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn)

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn)*</sup>

You have to select the data from your CTE, similar to this:

```sql
WITH CTE_Grand_Harvest_Total AS (
SELECT 
    zardi, COUNT(zardi) AS Count_ZARDI, SUM(Weight) AS Sum_Weight, Total_Harvest, Total_Harvest*COUNT(zardi)*SUM(Weight) AS Grand_Total
FROM 
    S1_PH_CROPS_clean_final_minus_money_matters
WHERE  
    Work.dbo.S1_PH_CROPS_clean_final_minus_money_matters.cropNamePH = 'Maize'
GROUP BY 
    Total_Harvest, zardi
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Grand_Harvest_Total;
```

Then you are compliant with the `SELECT` and CTE definitions.